# Get the Correlation ID from MQ as string

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am setting the Correlation ID while sending the message to MQ. And I need to use the CorrelationID from the COA of the message I pushed for the further processing.

I am setting the correlation ID and sending the message to queue using the below code.

```
MQMessage message = createMQMessage("12345");
message.write("Some message to push".getBytes());
queue.put(message);

private MQMessage createMQMessage(String corrID){

        MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
        message.messageFlags = MQConstants.MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED;

        if (ackQueueName != null) {

            message.messageType = MQConstants.MQMT_REQUEST;
            message.replyToQueueManagerName = ackQueueManagerName;
            message.replyToQueueName = ackQueueName;
            message.report = MQConstants.MQRO_COA | MQConstants.MQRO_COD;
            message.correlationId = corrID.getBytes();



        }
        return message;
    }
```

I am reading the replyQueue from another application to get the COA and extract the correlation ID for further processing.

But the correlation ID is in `byte[]` format and I used the below method `getHexString` to get the string. But all I got is 48 digit Hex format of my correlation ID like

> 414d5120514d41444556202020202020b5ca0d5b13b3bb20

```
public static String getHexString(byte[] b) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
            result += Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }


        return result;

    }
```

All I need is the approach to convert the **48digit HexString** to the Original Correlation ID I set. I tried using the below method to convert, but its giving me the junk data.

```
public static String hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
        int l = hex.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[l/2];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
            data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return new String(data);
    }
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString[byte[])`

Comment: ok.. I am not asking how to convert the byte[] to String. I am able to get the String using the method `getHexString`. MQ manager internally converting the string to Hex.. All I wanted to convert the Hex String to original String format..

I am editing my question to make it clear.. Sorry..!!

Comment: `new String (byte[])`

Comment: COA messages return the message ID of the request in the correlation ID of the response.

Comment: @JoshMc Thank you so much.. Thats the issue. I set the message ID myself, now I am getting it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your report options are not explicitly set.

> **MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID**  *This is the default action*, and
>   indicates that if a report or reply is generated as a result of this
>   message, the MsgId of this message is copied to the CorrelId of the
>   report or reply message.

Because of the default action, you will never receive the initial Correlation ID of your message. As Roger mentioned in his answer, it is bad practice to set the *MsgID* programmatically. Simply use the following option to have the *CorrelID* copied to the report message:

> **MQRO_PASS_CORREL_ID** If a report or reply is generated as a result of
>   this message, the CorrelId of this message is copied to the CorrelId
>   of the report or reply message.

```
message.report = MQConstants.MQRO_COA 
                 | MQConstants.MQRO_COD 
                 | MQConstants.MQRO_PASS_CORREL_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks. I got to know the Correlation ID should have 24 Bytes not more than that. Is other any alternative way other than setting correlation ID?

Comment: You also have the option of setting `MQRO_COA_WITH_DATA`. This adds the first 100 bytes of the message to the report.

Answer (score 2):

> I set the message ID myself, now I am getting it fine

Do NOT set the message's messageId yourself.  Let the queue manager create a unique messageId for each message that is put to a queue.  If you need to pass information along with the message either (1) put it in the message data/payload or (2) add a Message Property (aka Named Property) to the message.

If you create your own messageId then there is a chance of duplicate messageIds which is a very bad thing and goes against Best Practices.  IBM MQ Best Practices says to let the queue manager create a unique messageId.